# How do I set up a route to access nested objects in mongodb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, backend

The route to get our forms is setup correctly and [returns something similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8Hif.jpg). In the questions array I have stored question objects but I can't figure out how to access them. My code currently looks like:

```
router.route('/:post_id/:q_id')

.get(function (request, response) 
{

forms.findById(request.params.post_id,function(error,form) 
{
    if (error) 
    {
        response.send({error: error});
    }
   else 
   {
        for (var i in form.questions)
        {
            if (form.questions[i] == request.params.q_id)
            {
                questions = form.questions[i];
                response.json({singleQuestion: questions});
            }
        }     
    }    
});
})
```

This returns [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7J1u.jpg)

I am wondering how to get the object and read the fields in the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to do the following:

```js
router.get('/:formId/:questionId', (req, res) => {
  Form.findOne({
    _id: req.params.formId,
    questions: req.params.questionId
  }).populate('questions').then(form => {
   if (!form) {
      return res.status(404).json({error: 'Form not found'});
   };
   res.json({
      singleQuestion: form.questions.find(q => q._id.toString() == req.params.questionId)
   });
  }).catch(err => res.status(500).json({error: 'Internal error'}));
});
```

However, it seems this route is set up to retrieve question objects given a form. It may be smarter to make the following modification to your Form 'get' request:

```js
router.get('/form/:formId', (req, res) => {
  Form.findById(req.params.formId).populate('questions').exec((err, data) => {
    if (err || !data) {
      res.status(404).json({error: 'Form not found'});
    } else {
      res.json({data});
    }
  });
});
```

Have a look at [mongoose's docs for populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) - essentially, it'll swap the questionIds for the question objects themselves. Consider it an application-side join.